# How to use Javascript slice to extract first and last letter of a string?

Tags: javascript, string

How to use JavaScript `slice` to extract the first and last letter of a string?

Eg: `"Hello World"`

I need the result as `"dH"`.

Following is my jsfiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/vSAs8/

Comment: Wouldn't something like `str[str.length-1] + str[0]` be enough here?

Comment: s.substring(s.length-1)+s.substring(0,1);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the cleanest solution :

```
var output = input.slice(-1)+input[0];
```

If you want more `slice`, there's also

```
var output = input.slice(-1)+input.slice(0,1);
```

And here are alternate fun (and less efficient) solutions :

```
var output = input.replace(/^(.).*(.)$/,'$2$1');
```

or

```
var output = input.match(/^.|.$/g).reverse().join('');
```

Comment: any solution in 1 step?

Comment: What does that mean "1 step" ? `input.slice(-1)+input[0]` is one expression, is very fast and one of the shortest possible.

Comment: One small caveat: accessing string characters via numeric properties is non-standard prior to ECMAScript 5. In practice, it's unsupported in IE <= 7. Therefore `input.slice(-1)+input.charAt(0)` would be safer.

Comment: @TimDown IE9 isn't supported anymore even by Google Mail. Supporting IE7 today would prevent so much of what we do that it's not worth trying.

Comment: It entirely depends on context. The reality for a significant number of web developers is that IE 7 remains in use (in some large corporations and schools, for example) and they have to deal with it. I agree it's becoming less of a concern, but it's not difficult in this case to head off a potential problem for the minority who do have to deal with IE 7 (which includes me, unfortunately).

Comment: Poor you. I guess you're not having much fun with canvas, webrtc or websockets...

Answer (score 2):

Substr works as well:

```
alert(test.substr(-1,1) + test.substr(0,1));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a.charAt(a.length-1) + a.charAt(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = " Virat Kohali " 
var get_string_label = function(str){ 
  str = str.split(" "); 
  str = str.filter(res=>res.length>0); 
  str = str.map(function(res){ 
    return res[0].toUpperCase(); 
  }); 
  str = str.join(""); 
  return str; 
}; 
console.log(get_string_label(str));
```

**str.split(" ")**;  method splits a String object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings, where it will find space in string.

then **str.filter(res=>res.length>0)**  will filter out string having zero length *(for "virat kohali" string you will get empty sub-string)*
after that using map function you can fetch your first letter

Comment: use format options and add explanation to your answer. Don't just write codes

Comment: Thanks for advice @Harsh. Please find the edited code