# How can i remove zero from input number in form javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code and I want to remove first zero from phone number.

```
mobile = $('#country_code').val();
        mobile += input.val();
```

Country code is: `966`

Phone input is: `055642444`

And output in this code is: `966055642444`

I want it to be `96655642444` without zero after country code.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Javascript slice to extract first and last letter of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951188/how-to-use-javascript-slice-to-extract-first-and-last-letter-of-a-string)

Comment: if str[0] == "0" then str = str.substring(1)

Comment: You can call `parseInt()` or `Number()` on the string to turn it into an int, which will remove leading zeros. Or you can use `.replace(/^0+/, '')`

Comment: @Chris G: Cant phone numbers start with multiple zeros? Atleast my office number does.

Comment: @Lain yes, which is why the dupe I linked and the three ways in my comment all remove one or more leading zeros :)

Comment: @Chris G: Exactly. Is it not wrong to remove more than one zero? If I try to call my number with all of them removed I get *invalid number*. It works without country code and the zeros or with adding the country code and only removing the first zero.

Comment: @Lain I see, I misread your comment. I'm reasonably sure that local phone numbers in Kyrgyzstan all have just one leading zero ;) just kidding, no idea, but OP will surely tell us

Answer (score 2):

You can use `substring` to remove the first `N` characters from a string.

First of all, assign a variable with the value of `input.val()`

```
let str = input.val()
```

Now, you can index the Nth element of `str` and check its value:

```
if (str[0] === "0") str = str.substring(1)
```

With this, you have successfully checked if the first character is `"0"` and reassigned the `str` variable accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried parseInt(), integers don't have leading 0s - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

```
mobile = $('#country_code').val();
        mobile += parseInt(input.val());
```

Answer (score 1):

For this, I'd use `substring` which returns a new string. Example :

```js
mobile = '0652447766';
mobile = mobile.substring(1)
console.log('mobile = ', mobile)

>> mobile = '652447766'
```

Warning ! Calling `mobile.substring()` doesn't actually modify mobile ! Strings are immutable in Js, so you'll have to get the returned value of substring() with `mobile = mobile.substring(1)`

Hope it helped !

Answer (score 0):

If you store the value of the phone number in the html element `<input>` as a string - like this:

`<input type='text' />`

Then just use the native javascript `parseInt()` method to remove the leading zero, which removes the leading zero.

Like this:

```
const withoutZero = parseInt(input.val());
```

Or you can leave the value as a string, and if the string starts with "0", you can also delete it as follows:

```
const withoutZero = input.val().replace(/^0+/, '');
```